# How to get language name from language id in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the language name "en-US" or "en", which maps to English. I want to convert it to its language code 0x0409.

Is there a built in windows API in C++ I can use to do this or do I have to implement it myself?

Edit: I made a mistake in my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GetLocaleInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318101(v=vs.85).aspx) with the [`LOCALE_SNAME` locale information type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373858(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
int locale_id = 0x0409;
constexpr int max_locale_sname_len = 85;
TSTR[max_locale_sname_len] locale_iso_name;
int result = GetLocaleInfo(
    MAKELCID(locale_id),
    LOCALE_SNAME,
    locale_iso_name,
    max_locale_sname_len
);
```

Comment: Gah, your edit made this answer useless. Can’t be bothered to rewrite it now, but the answer stays similar, just use `GetLocaleInfoEx` with the suitable constant instead.

Comment: That answers my original question, thank you. I made a mistake though, its supposed to be the other way around. I'll try with GetLocalInfoEx, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There exists an [GetLocaleInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318101(v=vs.85).aspx) function, I think that is what you are looking for?